# How do I take a string of numbers in Python 2.7.2 and make each number its own element in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

I have a string of numbers.  I would like to take each number and insert it into a list where each number is its own element in the list so I can use a For loop to search for that number.  In the code below I have written an example:

```
string = "3, 4, 5, 99"

a_list = []

a_list.append(string)

for i in range (0, len(a_list)):
    if int(a_list[i]) == 99:
        print "yes 99 is in here"
```

I would like the loop to print "yes 99 is in here" because it is.  I think the problem with my code is that entire string is listed as element 0 (the only element) in the list.  Please help!!  I know this is basic, but I'm having trouble finding the solution online. I'm new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string to separate each number as it's own element. Luckily Python has your back with that.

```
>>> a_list= string.split(", ")
>>> a_list
['3', '4', '5', '99']
```

Comment: This is a list of strings, not a list of integers

Comment: @Andy: He explicitly converting to `int` in the `for` loop and I didn't want to go on about the dangers of converting without checking to keep the post on topic and simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = map(int, s.split(','))
if 99 in l:
    print "yes 99 is in here"
```

We are splitting your list at the comma and then mapping this to an integer type. Otherwise you'd have a list filled with strings.

After the first line, your list looks like this:

```
[3, 4, 5, 99]
```

Your check then is as simple as seeing if `99` is in your list (`l`)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string_list = [float(i) for i in string.split(', ')]

if 99 in string_list:
    print '99 is here'
```

The string split method creates a list of the individual numbers but they are strings. So the `[float(i) for i in string.split(', ')]` part converts them all to floats. You can use `int(i)` if you know they will be integers or you want to interpret them as such.

Answer (score 0):

remove spaces at the beginning and end (if present) using [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

then split the string with ',' as delimiter using [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which returns a list of strings.

Convert each element in list to `int`

```
string = "3, 4, 5, 99"

strings = string.strip().split(",")

a_list = [int(i) for i in strings]

for i in range (0, len(a_list)):
    if int(a_list[i]) == 99:
        print "yes 99 is in here"
```

Comment: `strings = string.split(",")` should probably be `strings = strings.split(",")`, or you could just fold into the previous line as `strings = string.strip().split(",")`.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you explained how your code works and how it answers the question.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead:

```
if string == "99" or\
   string.startswith("99,") or\
   string.endswith(", 99") or\
   ", 99," in string: print "Hooray!"
```